# How to switch between Grid and List view using Typescript Angular4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Working in an Angular4  application ,In this I need to have a UI which contains the Grid view and List View options for displaying products .

I have designed the UI but I need to do some magics in Typescript,So I looking for SO.

I have referred some other examples nothing is worked for me .

Please refer my Stackblitz File : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s8oogm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Where I have the HTMl,CSS and I want to enable the functions for switch between List and Grid View.

When I switch to list view I need to show the product like the below image ,For that my stackblitz file I have done the CSS but I don't know it's right or wrong .

Grid View

[image]

List View

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: create separate component for List and Grid and pass data using Output decorator to child component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create 2 nested components AppGridProduct and AppListProduct and call show them based on your display mode and send data to each component using Input:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
  <button class="btn btn-white" type="button"(click)="onDisplayModeChange(1)"
                [ngClass]="{'btn-primary active': displayMode === 1}" >
                <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-white" type="button"  (click)="onDisplayModeChange(2)"
                [ngClass]="{'btn-primary active': displayMode === 2}" >
                <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
  </button>
 </div>
 <!-- grid -->
 <div class="row" *ngIf="displayMode === 1">
   <app-grid-container *ngFor='let product of productsList' [product]="product"></app-grid-container>
 </div>
 <!-- List -->
 <div class="row" *ngIf="displayMode === 2">
   <app-list-container *ngFor='let product of productsList' [product]="product></app-list-container>
 </div>
```

and in your component.ts

```
onDisplayModeChange(mode: number): void {
  this.displayMode = mode;
}
```

add this to your css:

```
button.active {
 color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,the active button color is not changed ,How to fix it

Comment: Is there any way to handle grid view and list view on single div? Right now this solution is based on div show / hide. What if I need this functionality on single div not 2 separate divs ?

Comment: you can use only one child component but you have to add an input type (list or grid), your child component will load the correct view base on the type <app-container [type]="list" or [type]="grid"  *ngFor='let product of productsList' [product]="product" ></app-container>

Comment: Good way to handle table and list view.

Answer (score 0):

add this insted of class='card' [ngClass]="isCard?'card':'list'"

and in your controller switch isCard flag based on the user input

You need to implement card and list classes and their child classes based on the ui requirements, also you can use isCard flag to show hide elements specific for grid and list view.